# Error when running parcel: unknow option -d

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have this react js where the script on the package.json contains this command that gets triggered when i run "npm start"
`"parcel %INIT_CWD%/index.html -d ./dist"`
But i get the error `parcel: unknown option -d` and i don't know why, it is supposed to recognize it right ?
P.S: this is parcel's version that i'm using "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.2"

thanks in advance

Comment: When I look in the docs of that npm package, there is no CLI option `-d` Maybe you mean `--dist-dir` but this has no shortcut to `d` ...